# Concerning Primitive roots and exponents.

Tags: congruences, primitive-roots

If for any $u$,such that 1 < u < p; given $\bmod p$; if $m^u \equiv u V \pmod{p}$ where $p$ does not divide $(V - 1)$ for any $V$  then $m$ is not a primitive root. Is this true?

Comment: I would say it is not true, unless you have a more restrictive definition of $V(u)$. As it stands, $V(u)$ can apparently be any value. Can you perhaps give an example for, say, $p=7$?

Comment: What I'm really asking is if m^u is not congruent to u mod p for any u , such that 1 < u < m ; then m is not a primitive root mod p. 2 is not a primitive root mod 7 and for any n , such that 1 < n < 7;  2^n is not = n mod 7 ,I think.

Comment: "for any V that is dependent on u"? What does this mean?

Comment: Forgive poor editing.

Comment: So if m^u is not congruent to u mod p ,( for any u < p )then m is not a primitive root mod p.

Comment: @201044  If $m^u$ is not congruent to some $u \pmod{p}$ then what could it be congruent to except $0$?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, the question appears to be this: "If $m$ is a primitive root modulo a prime $p$ then for any integer $1 \le u < p$ we have $m^u \equiv s \pmod{p}$ where $1 \le s < p$."

Since $s$ can be represented by a residue system between $1 \le s < p$, this is true for any $m$ not congruent to $0$ modulo $p$ and so it is also true for primitive roots.

Comment: If there exists no u such that p divides (m^u - u) where 1<= u, m < p then m can't be a primitive root mod p ; is this true?

Comment: For $m$ to be a primitive root, it has to generate all of the integers modulo $p$ between $1$ and $p-1$.  The way you phrase this makes me wonder if you are asking whether there must exist some specific $u$ such that $m^u \equiv u \pmod{p}$ in order for $m$ to be a primitive root.  For example, $2^3 \equiv 3 \pmod{5}$.  However, $3$ is a primitive root modulo $5$, but there is no specific $u$ that works like that: $3^1 \equiv 3 \pmod{5}$, $3^2 \equiv 4 \pmod{5}$, $3^3 = 27 \equiv 2 \pmod{5}$ and $3^4 = 81 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$.

Comment: Yes ,in order for m to be a primitive root must there exist a u such that m^u = u mod p ? As is previously mentioned this doesn't work with 3 but what about larger m?

Comment: @201044  Good question.  I don't know.  For primitive roots modulo $5$, one of the primitive roots has the property, namely $2$, while the other, $3$, doesn't.